# how do we read a csv file and display the same in dojo?

Tags: dojo

i want to write a dojo code where upon a button click i want to read a .csv file and display the .csv file in a datagrid using Dojo. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What version of Dojo are you going to use? (There are some modules that work in older versions, but are deprecated now), what did you try so far? I mean, if we're going to put the same effort in answering as you did in making your question, then I don't think you will get a lot of answers.

Comment: I am using Dojo 1.9. I am very new to dojo (started working on it since 3 weeks). I found about the csvstore in dojo. but I dont know how to use this.

Comment: Well, that's actually the module I was talking about. It's deprecated now so you shouldn't use it. I recommend that you retrieve the file using `dojo/request`, parse it manually, put it in a `dojo/store` and connect that to your grid. Read @MiBrock's answer for more info about populating your grid.

Answer (score 0):

Your best try is to retrieve the data using the [`dojo/request/xhr`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html) module, with it you can retrieve an external CSV file. For example:

```js
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr) {
    xhr.get("myfile.csv", {
        handleAs: "text"
    }).then(function(data) {
        // Use data
    });
});
```

---

Well, now you have the data as a string in your `data` parameter, what you now need to do is parse that string. The easiest way is to split your string on each enter, for example:

```js
var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
```

The \r is optional (depends on the system you're using), but now you have each line seperated in an array element in `lines`. The next step is to retrieve each seperate value, for example by doing:

```js
require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array) {
    /** Rest of code */
    array.forEach(lines, function(line) {
        var cells = line.split(',');
    });
});
```

---

Then you have your data splitted by each comma. The next step is that you have to change it to a format that the `dojox/grid/DataGrid` can read. This means that you will probably convert the first line of your CSV content to your headers (if they contain headers) and the rest of the data to objects (in stead of arrays of strings).

You can get the first line with:

```js
var headers = lines[0].split(',');
```

And the rest of the data with:

```js
var otherData = lines.splice(1);
```

---

Now you should carefully read the documentation @MiBrock gave you, and with it you can transform the simple array of strings to the correct format.

The headers should become an array of objects like this:

```js
[{ name: "display name", field: "field name" }, { /** other objects */ }]
```

I did that by doing:

```js
array.map(headers, function(header) {
    return {
        field: header,
        name: header
    };
});
```

This will actually convert `[ "a", "b" ]` to:

```js
[{ field: "a", name: "a" }, { field: "b", name: "b" }]
```

---

Now you need to convert all other lines to objects containing a field with name `a` and a field with name `b`, you can do that using:

```js
array.map(otherData, function(line) {
    var cells = line.split(','), obj = {};
    array.forEach(cells, function(cell, idx) {
        obj[headers[idx]] = cell;
    });
    return obj:
});
```

This will actually retrieve the fieldname by retrieving the corresponding header value and output it as a single object.

Now you can put it in a grid, look at @MiBrock's answer for more details about how to do that. The final result would look a bit like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/UH3TX/1/).

---

**Note**: Next time you encounter a problem you can't solve, handle the parts you actually **can** solve first and then ask a question about the other parts. I mean, it's hard to believe that you can actually not solve any of this by yourself. You should try and learn it by yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

The [dojo-smore](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore) project includes a [CSV object store](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore/blob/master/Csv.js) that loads data from CSV into an in-memory store which can then be used with any component that supports object stores, like [dgrid](http://dgrid.io). You shouldn’t try to do it yourself, like Dimitri M suggested, and you shouldn’t use the dojox grids, which are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dojox.data.CsvStore](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/data/CsvStore.html#id2) to read a CSV store and use it in a data grid.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/index.html#dojox-grid-index

and here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/populating_datagrid/

This should help you to start with your Programming. 
If you need further help, show us what you have tried to solve the Problem by posting your code and we'll be glad to help you.

Regards, Miriam